# SQLite on Android E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting date=05/04/2021 time=60000.0

Tags: java, android-sqlite

I am making a db in Sqlite on android studio.

this is my code:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@NotNull SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //SQL - Structured Query Language
        String CREATE_DATA_TIME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + UtilDB.TABLE_DATA_TIME + "("
                + UtilDB.KEY_DATE + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
                + UtilDB.KEY_TIME + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_DATA_TIME_TABLE); //creating our table

    }





 public void addWorkTime(@NotNull WorkTime workTime) {

//        if there is just a date, it will update this worktime
        if (thereIsADate(workTime.getDate()))
            updateWorkTime(workTime);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(UtilDB.KEY_DATE, workTime.getDate());
        values.put(UtilDB.KEY_TIME, workTime.getTime());

        Log.d(TAG, workTime.toString());

        //Insert to row
        db.insert(UtilDB.TABLE_DATA_TIME, null, values); // TODO

        Log.d(TAG, "addWorkTime: " + "item added");
        db.close(); //closing db connection!

    }
```

But i have this problem:

```
2021-05-04 21:23:02.697 16874-16874/com.application.care E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting date=05/04/2021 time=60000.0
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1474)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
        at com.application.care.data.HandlerDB.addWorkTime(HandlerDB.java:78)
        at com.application.care.ui.home.HandlerCountDownTime.setView(HandlerCountDownTime.java:61)
        at com.application.care.ui.home.HomeFragment.manageCountDownTime(HomeFragment.java:27)
        at com.application.care.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:48)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2722)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1188)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 2021-05-04 21:23:02.700 16874-16874/com.application.care D/HandlerCountDownTime: []
```

How i can resolve?

**Edit: i try do reinstall DB but there is this problem:**

> 2021-05-05 17:54:01.039 18089-18089/com.application.care
> E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting date=05/05/2021 time=2.6133548E7
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: DataTime.date (code 1555)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native
> Method)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1474)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
> at com.application.care.data.HandlerDB.addWorkTime(HandlerDB.java:78)
> at com.application.care.ui.home.HandlerCountDownTime$2.onEnd(HandlerCountDownTime.java:94)
> at cn.iwgang.countdownview.CountdownView$1.onFinish(CountdownView.java:139)
> at cn.iwgang.countdownview.CustomCountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CustomCountDownTimer.java:106)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: And what returns getDate and getTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your issue is that you have changed the onCreate method from:-

```
public void onCreate(@NotNull SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //SQL - Structured Query Language
    String CREATE_DATA_TIME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + UtilDB.TABLE_DATA_TIME + "("
            + UtilDB.KEY_DATE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," //<<<<<<<<<< WAS THIS
            + UtilDB.KEY_TIME + " INTEGER" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DATA_TIME_TABLE); //creating our table

}
```

to

```
public void onCreate(@NotNull SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //SQL - Structured Query Language
    String CREATE_DATA_TIME_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + UtilDB.TABLE_DATA_TIME + "("
            + UtilDB.KEY_DATE + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," //<<<<<<<<<< NOW THIS
            + UtilDB.KEY_TIME + " INTEGER" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DATA_TIME_TABLE); //creating our table

}
```

- see comments indicated by `//<<<<<<<<<<`

But have run the first version, made the changed and then run the second version without deleting the database.

The **DataType Mismatch** will only happen if the an attempt is made to insert/update a row and that the **rowid** column or an alias of the rowid column is not an integer.

- coding `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is special in that it makes the column and alias of the normally hidden **rowid** column.

See [SQLite Result and Error Codes - Result Code meanings](https://sqlite.org/rescode.html#result_code_meanings)

> **(20) SQLITE_MISMATCH** The SQLITE_MISMATCH error code indicates a
> datatype mismatch.
>
> SQLite is normally very forgiving about mismatches between the type of
> a value and the declared type of the container in which that value is
> to be stored. For example, SQLite allows the application to store a
> large BLOB in a column with a declared type of BOOLEAN. But in a few
> cases, SQLite is strict about types. The SQLITE_MISMATCH error is
> returned in those few cases when the types do not match.
>
> **The rowid of a table must be an integer. Attempt to set the rowid to
> anything other than an integer (or a NULL which will be automatically
> converted into the next available integer rowid) results in an
> SQLITE_MISMATCH error.**

**Fix**

The simple fix if you can afford to lose any existing data is to delete the database, this can be achieved by uninstalling the App. You can then just rerun the App.

If you have existing data that needs to be saved (probably unlikely as the data in the data column may be useless), then you need to introduce a one-off run that will:-

1. Create a new table with the final column definitions ensuring that the table's name is different  e.g. your_table_NEW.
2. Populate the new table from the original table
3. Rename the original table using [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)
4. Rename the new table to the original table name
5. DROP the new table.